# How do I make the pandas.scatter_matrix chart appear larger in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Python 3.6.5 and Pandas 0.23.0 in Jupyter Notebook.

Some of my relevant imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
```

My code to generate the scatter matrix

```
scatter_matrix(df_obscured)
```

Some potentially important notes about my dataframe...I have an index field, I have a datetime64[ns] field, I have about 20 float64 fields that I'm looking at.

**My problem:**
My scatter matrix is super small. Maybe 2 to 3 hundred pixels wide. Most of the output looks like:

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000021AC2DDBFD0>,
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000021AC3033DA0>,
```

How do I make the scatter matrix chart larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scatter_matrix` takes a figsize parameter:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.html

Be aware that as with other matplotlib 'figsize' parameters, the size specified should be in inches, not in pixels.